# Is there any library that parses JVM bytecode and gives you offset of each instruction?

Tags: java, parsing, bytecode

Suppose you have a class like this:

```
package org.example.foo;
public class Foo {
    private int y;

    // more code here

    public int foo(int x) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Off the top of my head, the `foo` method should look more or less like this:

```
ILOAD_1
ALOAD_0
GETFIELD org/example/foo/Foo I;
IADD
IRETURN
```

Is there any library that would permit me to parse the .class file into these instructions *and let me know at which offset in the .class file each of the instructions can be found*? I've used ObjectWeb's ASM to both parse and generate .class files, but it doesn't provide this information out of the box.

Comment: Offset into the method code or the classfile itself? The first is much more useful. Anyway, there are numerous ways to get the offset, the question is what format you want them in and whether you need a library, commandline tool, etc.

Comment: Either would work. If you have offset into the method code, you can convert it into the offset into the classfile and vice versa. I would need a library, though, a commandline tool won't work for what I have in mind.

Comment: Oh sorry. I just patched Krakatau to print instruction offsets. It only took a minute or two. But if you want a library, that's not going to help much.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Too bad it's not a JVM library itself.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to check the ASM source out of curiosity. Here's the loop which reads and visits the instructions. Offset is stored in a local variable but doesn't get passed to the visitor for some reason. Anyway, if you want to use ASM, it would appear that the only options are to either modify the code yourself or to use ugly reflection hacks. If you want to modify ASM, just change all the `vist*Insn` calls here to pass in the `offset` variable.

```
u = codeStart;
while (u < codeEnd) {
    int offset = u - codeStart;

    // visits the label and line number for this offset, if any
    Label l = labels[offset];
    if (l != null) {
        mv.visitLabel(l);
        if ((context.flags & SKIP_DEBUG) == 0 && l.line > 0) {
            mv.visitLineNumber(l.line, l);
        }
    }

    // visits the frame for this offset, if any
    while (FRAMES && frame != null
            && (frame.offset == offset || frame.offset == -1)) {
        // if there is a frame for this offset, makes the visitor visit
        // it, and reads the next frame if there is one.
        if (frame.offset != -1) {
            if (!zip || unzip) {
                mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_NEW, frame.localCount,
                        frame.local, frame.stackCount, frame.stack);
            } else {
                mv.visitFrame(frame.mode, frame.localDiff, frame.local,
                        frame.stackCount, frame.stack);
            }
        }
        if (frameCount > 0) {
            stackMap = readFrame(stackMap, zip, unzip, frame);
            --frameCount;
        } else {
            frame = null;
        }
    }

    // visits the instruction at this offset
    int opcode = b[u] & 0xFF;
    switch (ClassWriter.TYPE[opcode]) {
    case ClassWriter.NOARG_INSN:
        mv.visitInsn(opcode);
        u += 1;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.IMPLVAR_INSN:
        if (opcode > Opcodes.ISTORE) {
            opcode -= 59; // ISTORE_0
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ISTORE + (opcode >> 2),
                    opcode & 0x3);
        } else {
            opcode -= 26; // ILOAD_0
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD + (opcode >> 2), opcode & 0x3);
        }
        u += 1;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.LABEL_INSN:
        mv.visitJumpInsn(opcode, labels[offset + readShort(u + 1)]);
        u += 3;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.LABELW_INSN:
        mv.visitJumpInsn(opcode - 33, labels[offset + readInt(u + 1)]);
        u += 5;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.WIDE_INSN:
        opcode = b[u + 1] & 0xFF;
        if (opcode == Opcodes.IINC) {
            mv.visitIincInsn(readUnsignedShort(u + 2), readShort(u + 4));
            u += 6;
        } else {
            mv.visitVarInsn(opcode, readUnsignedShort(u + 2));
            u += 4;
        }
        break;
    case ClassWriter.TABL_INSN: {
        // skips 0 to 3 padding bytes
        u = u + 4 - (offset & 3);
        // reads instruction
        int label = offset + readInt(u);
        int min = readInt(u + 4);
        int max = readInt(u + 8);
        Label[] table = new Label[max - min + 1];
        u += 12;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) {
            table[i] = labels[offset + readInt(u)];
            u += 4;
        }
        mv.visitTableSwitchInsn(min, max, labels[label], table);
        break;
    }
    case ClassWriter.LOOK_INSN: {
        // skips 0 to 3 padding bytes
        u = u + 4 - (offset & 3);
        // reads instruction
        int label = offset + readInt(u);
        int len = readInt(u + 4);
        int[] keys = new int[len];
        Label[] values = new Label[len];
        u += 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            keys[i] = readInt(u);
            values[i] = labels[offset + readInt(u + 4)];
            u += 8;
        }
        mv.visitLookupSwitchInsn(labels[label], keys, values);
        break;
    }
    case ClassWriter.VAR_INSN:
        mv.visitVarInsn(opcode, b[u + 1] & 0xFF);
        u += 2;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.SBYTE_INSN:
        mv.visitIntInsn(opcode, b[u + 1]);
        u += 2;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.SHORT_INSN:
        mv.visitIntInsn(opcode, readShort(u + 1));
        u += 3;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.LDC_INSN:
        mv.visitLdcInsn(readConst(b[u + 1] & 0xFF, c));
        u += 2;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.LDCW_INSN:
        mv.visitLdcInsn(readConst(readUnsignedShort(u + 1), c));
        u += 3;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.FIELDORMETH_INSN:
    case ClassWriter.ITFMETH_INSN: {
        int cpIndex = items[readUnsignedShort(u + 1)];
        boolean itf = b[cpIndex - 1] == ClassWriter.IMETH;
        String iowner = readClass(cpIndex, c);
        cpIndex = items[readUnsignedShort(cpIndex + 2)];
        String iname = readUTF8(cpIndex, c);
        String idesc = readUTF8(cpIndex + 2, c);
        if (opcode < Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL) {
            mv.visitFieldInsn(opcode, iowner, iname, idesc);
        } else {
            mv.visitMethodInsn(opcode, iowner, iname, idesc, itf);
        }
        if (opcode == Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE) {
            u += 5;
        } else {
            u += 3;
        }
        break;
    }
    case ClassWriter.INDYMETH_INSN: {
        int cpIndex = items[readUnsignedShort(u + 1)];
        int bsmIndex = context.bootstrapMethods[readUnsignedShort(cpIndex)];
        Handle bsm = (Handle) readConst(readUnsignedShort(bsmIndex), c);
        int bsmArgCount = readUnsignedShort(bsmIndex + 2);
        Object[] bsmArgs = new Object[bsmArgCount];
        bsmIndex += 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < bsmArgCount; i++) {
            bsmArgs[i] = readConst(readUnsignedShort(bsmIndex), c);
            bsmIndex += 2;
        }
        cpIndex = items[readUnsignedShort(cpIndex + 2)];
        String iname = readUTF8(cpIndex, c);
        String idesc = readUTF8(cpIndex + 2, c);
        mv.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(iname, idesc, bsm, bsmArgs);
        u += 5;
        break;
    }
    case ClassWriter.TYPE_INSN:
        mv.visitTypeInsn(opcode, readClass(u + 1, c));
        u += 3;
        break;
    case ClassWriter.IINC_INSN:
        mv.visitIincInsn(b[u + 1] & 0xFF, b[u + 2]);
        u += 3;
        break;
    // case MANA_INSN:
    default:
        mv.visitMultiANewArrayInsn(readClass(u + 1, c), b[u + 3] & 0xFF);
        u += 4;
        break;
    }

    // visit the instruction annotations, if any
    while (tanns != null && tann < tanns.length && ntoff <= offset) {
        if (ntoff == offset) {
            int v = readAnnotationTarget(context, tanns[tann]);
            readAnnotationValues(v + 2, c, true,
                    mv.visitInsnAnnotation(context.typeRef,
                            context.typePath, readUTF8(v, c), true));
        }
        ntoff = ++tann >= tanns.length || readByte(tanns[tann]) < 0x43 ? -1
                : readUnsignedShort(tanns[tann] + 1);
    }
    while (itanns != null && itann < itanns.length && nitoff <= offset) {
        if (nitoff == offset) {
            int v = readAnnotationTarget(context, itanns[itann]);
            readAnnotationValues(v + 2, c, true,
                    mv.visitInsnAnnotation(context.typeRef,
                            context.typePath, readUTF8(v, c), false));
        }
        nitoff = ++itann >= itanns.length
                || readByte(itanns[itann]) < 0x43 ? -1
                : readUnsignedShort(itanns[itann] + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.lang.instrument` to get the bytes of the classfile, and [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to parse it.  There are other libraries like [JavaAssist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) that will help you do this at a higher level of abstraction.  ASM is a bare metal bytecode instrumentation library.

You claim you've used ASM - but it doesn't provide 'this information out of the box'.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: The whole purpose of the question was to see whether there was an easy way to find out the offset of each instruction in the class file. ASM does not provide that information out of the box. I could try to come up with some hack that would give me that information, but that hack would likely be rather fragile.

Comment: after you've edited the question, and clarified that point, yes, I agree, my answer is incomplete...

Comment: On the other hand, it seems that my question is a duplicate of the one you linked to. Unfortunately, the answer is just the kind of hack I was talking about ;)